vue . order-in-components. eslint
подскажите пожалуйста можно ли настроить eslint так чтобы он контролировал порядок в компоненте как по ссылке для optionsAPI: https://armano2.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/rules/order-in-components.html но при этом надо контролировать порядок синтаксисе CompositionAPI ? т.е. если правило что сначала computed а потом methods будет ли eslint понимать что порядок не верный и показывать ошибку в случае:
const changeMessage = () => {
  message.value = 'Hello, Composition API!';
};
// Вычисляемое свойство
const uppercaseMessage = computed(() => {
  return message.value.toUpperCase();
});

наверно нет.
Вопрос ести ли варианты ?

У вас проблема в логике. Одной из главных целей и задач Composition API было как раз-таки дать возможность компоновать фичи компонентов логически, а не структурно. Если вы хотите, чтобы методы были с методами, а компьютеды с комьютедами, то вам нужен Options API. В Components API же нужно компоновать по функциональности.
